# Lisp: Generating a list of 10 random integers

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

this is part of a my first homework in common lisp.

We have to define a variable representing any 10 random integers from 0 to 100:
I am not sure what is being asked here. 
Should I write: `(setf var1 '())`

Then, we have to define a function that generates a list of 10 random integers and returns a list that contains those numbers.

Here is what I wrote, but I keep getting NIL as my output. Do you know what's wrong with the code:

```
(setf *random-state* (make-random-state t))
(setf var1 '())


(defun randlist (var1)
(dotimes (i 10)
    (setf temp (random 101))
        (cons 'temp var1  ) ) )
```

Comment: You are hiding the global variable `var1` with the function parameter named `var1`. Also, there's no need to use a global variable, just make the function return a new list and assign the result to a variable. Global variables are evil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write a function that *returns* a new list with 10 random integers:

```
(defun randlist ()
  (let ((lst ()))
    (dotimes (i 10)
       (setf lst (cons (random 101) lst)))
   lst))
```

And then you can assign its result to a variable:

```
(defvar var1 (randlist))
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/fol05)**.

Comment: What would be the difference between `(setf var1 (randlist))` and `(defparameter var1 (randlist))` ?

Comment: `setf` can be seen as a more general *assignment* operator. It's typically used to *change* the value of a previously declared variable. `defvar` is very similar to `defparameter`, but it'll only allow you to define a variable value once. Check the final part of this demo http://ideone.com/5b8iw that I've created to see the differences.

Comment: Better use `push` instead of that `setf`-`cons` combination.  Just for measure, I think that the most straightforward way is `(loop :repeat 10 :collect (random 101))`.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to initialize `*random-state*` like that. That's the default anyway. You'd need to initialize it if you have a different implementation of random number generator.

While `(setf whatever nil)` will probably work, this is not the way you declare variables. `setf` is a macro for assigning values to symbols. Normally you first create symbols and then assign to them. If you need a dynamic variable, your options are `defparamter` or `defvar` macros, e.g.:

```
(defparameter var1 nil)
(defvar var2 nil)
```

Your function `randlist` returns `nil` as this is what `dotimes` macro returns, and this is the last form executed in the function. You could've changed it to return `var1`, but the use of dynamic variables, especially in this way is not a good coding practice. It sounds from the task as if you were asked to simply write a function that returns a list of ten integers, no need to also assign that to a dynamic variable outside the function.

```
(defun randlist ()
  (loop for i from 0 below 10 collect (random 101)))
```

Would be perhaps the simplest way to do it. But there are really lots and lots of other ways :)

Just for fun, here's an alternative, it's not particularly good, though. I hoped for it to be shorter, but it wasn't really :)

```
(defun random-list ()
  (mapcar #'random (make-list 10 :initial-element 101)))
```

Comment: Thanks for exposing me to different alternative. It's a good way for me to learn the language :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets do this with recursion:

```
(defun rnd-list()
  (rnd-list-1 10 10))

(defun rnd-list-1 (limit count)
  (cond ((<= count 0)
         nil)
        (t
         (cons (random limit)
               (rnd-list-1 limit (1- count))))))
```

Comment: good for when you are forced to ignore iteration for the sake of completing an assignment; meh

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do like this --

```
(defun rnd-list()
  (let (lst)
    (dotimes (n 100)
      (push (random 101) lst))
    (reverse lst)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Empowering [do](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm), iterate over `n` and define `lst` as a void list; when `n` reaches `10` return `lst`. On every iteration `push` one random number to `lst`.

```
(do ((n 1 (incf n))
     (lst ()))
    ((> n 10) lst)
  (push (random 101) lst))

=> (31 35 59 19 84 54 62 44 69 54)
```

Comment: Second line could be just `(lst))`, but this is as is :)